# Run linux shell commands in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, linux, shell, subprocess, centos7

I am creating a service manager to manage services such as apache , tomcat .. etc.
I can enable/disable services by srvmanage.sh enable <service_name> in shell.
I want to do this using python script. How to do it?

```
service_info = ServiceDB.query.filter_by(service_id=service_id).first()
    service_name = service_info.service
    subprocess.run(['/home/service_manager/bin/srvmanage.sh enable', service_name],shell=True)
```

what is the problem with this code ?

Comment: _what is the problem with this code_  : What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: Its not enable the service.

Comment: Did you try to trace the command (`set -x)? Did you check its exit code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing if you want to do this in python you may want more functionality. If not @programandoconro answer would do. However, you could also use the `subprocess module` to get more functionality. It will allow you to run a command with arguments and return a CompletedProcess instance. For example

```
import subprocess

# call to shell script
process = subprocess.run(['/path/to/script', options/variables], capture_output=True, text=True)
```

You can add in additional functionality by capturing the stderr/stdout and return code. For example:

```
# call to shell script
process = subprocess.run(['/path/to/script', options/variables], capture_output=True, text=True)
  
# return code of 0 test case. Successful run should return 0
if process.returncode != 0:
    print('There was a problem')
    exit(1)
```

Docs for subprocess is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `os` module to access system commands.

```
import os

os.system("srvmanage.sh enable <service_name>")
```

Comment: I need to pass service name as variable. because it can be differ.

Comment: How is this related to which way you are invoking the command? It's up to you to program as much variability into it as you need.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue .

```
operation = 'enable'
    service_operation_script = '/home/service_manager/bin/srvmanage.sh'
    service_status = subprocess.check_output(
       "sudo " +"/bin/bash " + service_operation_script + " " + operation + " " + service_name, shell=True)
    response = service_status.decode("utf-8")
    print(response)
```